# create value in function, then save pointer on value in global pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm relatively new to c++ and used to Java (which I like better).
I've got some pointer problem here. I created a minimal programm to simulate the behaviour of a more complex programm.

This is the code:

```
void test (int);
void test2(int*);

int* global [5];    //Array of int-pointer

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int z = 3;
    int y = 5;      
    cin >> z;       // get some number
    global[0] = &y; // global 0 points on y

    test(z);        // the corpus delicti

    //just printing stuff
    cout << global[0]<<endl;   //target address in pointer
    cout << &global[0]<<endl;  //address of pointer
    cout << *global[0]<<endl;  //target of pointer

    return 0; //whatever
}


//function doing random stuff and calling test2
void test (int b){
    int i = b*b;
    test2(&i);
    return;
}

//test2 called by test puts the address of int i (defined in test) into global[0]
void test2(int* j){
   global[0]= j; 
}
```

The tricky part is test2. I put the address of a variable I created in test into the global pointer array. Unfortunately, this program gives me a compiler error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int test(int)':
main.cpp:42:20: error: 'test2' was not declared in this scope
     return test2(&i);
                    ^
```

I can't find any scope problem here. I tried changing the int i of test into a global variable, but it didnt help, so I suppose, this isnt the reason.

Edit: It compiles now, but gives for cin = 20 the wrong values. *global[0] should be 400, but is 2130567168. It doesnt seem to be a int/uint problem. It is too far from 2,14e9.
Edit2: The input value doesnt matter.

Comment: Even if you fixed this code to compile, you're still storing a pointer to a temporary that immediately goes out of scope...

Comment: Please avoid global/class variables holding a temporary state passed around functions. I consider that as code obfuscation.

Comment: Actually the final programm shall instantiate a VI-Object (see NI-VIs). The pointer to this object shall be saved global to prevent the Object from deletion after the function has been left. The Object shall persist in memory. I suppose, that this is forbidden.

If I change the global Array from pointer to VI-Object, the program allocates 300 times the memory of one VI-Object (just for one type of VI-Objects). Even if I'm using just one entry. But I want the program to allocate memory only, when a VI-Object is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'test2' was not declared in this scope` It's because the compiler doesn't know what `test2` is. You need to add a function prototype above the main.

```
void test (int b);
void test2(int& j);
```

or just:

```
void test (int);
void test2(int&);
```

because at this time compiler only need to know the type of the arguments and not their names.

EDIT: Moving the function definition above the main without adding the prototype will also work, but it's better to use the prototypes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In Java I dont need this. And I still dont get exactly why, but if the compiler needs, it gets it.
But there is still a residual error, which I dont get. Or my google search suggests, that exactly what I want to do isnt allowed. :angry person behind the desktop:

Thats the error:

`main.cpp: In function 'void test(int)':
main.cpp:42:13: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int*'
     Test2(&i);
             ^
main.cpp:27:6: note: in passing argument 1 of 'void Test2(int&)'
 void Test2(int&);
      ^`

Comment: One obvious mistake is the way you call `test2` inside `test1`: `test2(&i);`. Since `test2` is defined like this `void test2(int&);` you need to call it like this: `test2(i);` This wiil fix one problem, tell if you more errors

Comment: I changed `test2(int)` to `test2(int*)`. It works now (thanks again), but it doesnt do what it should. I put i.e. 20 into z. After that, Test does 20*20=400 and puts it into int i. The address of i is written into global by test2. Now, `cout << *global[0]` should be 400, but it is 2130567168. Is this a unsigned/signed problem?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz Please update the code as it is now so I can take a look

Comment: Check. I'm a new member to stack exchange (but reader since a bit). So I've got to get familiar with all the buttons and stuff. The edit-function is pretty genius btw.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz Okay, in `void test2(int* j)` you access `j` which gives you it's address, because of test2 definition. In order to get `j`'s value you need to point at this address. So change: `global[0]= j; ` to `*global[0]= *j; ` and it will work

Comment: In that case, I would copy the value of j to the place, where global points to. I could live with that.

Answer (score 1):

Before a function can be called, the compiler must know about it.

So you either rearrange your function definitions such that `test2` comes first, `test` second and `main` last, or you put declarations of `test2` and `test1` before `main`:

```
void test2(int& j); // declaration
void test(int b);   // declaration

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // ...
}

void test(int b){ // definition
    // ...
}

void test2(int& j) { // definition
    // ...
}
```

This will then reveal a more serious error; you are calling `test2` with an `int*`, but it expects an `int&`. You can fix this by turning the call into `test2(i);`.

---

Once your functions are neatly split into declarations and definitions, it's time to perform the next step towards the typical C++ source-file management: put the declarations into header files (usually `*.h` or `*.hpp`) and `#include` them from the implementation file (usually `*.cpp`) that contains `main`. Then add two more implementation files for the two function definitions. Add corresponding `#include`s there, too. Don't forget about include guards in the headers.

Finally, compile the three implementation files separately and use a linker to create an executable from the three resulting object files.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare test2 before you call it. Every function needs to be declared before it is called.

add these lines above main to declare the functions;

```
void test2(int& j);
void test2(int& j);

int main(){...}
```